# Añadir ceros bajo condición en vista en MVC

Tags: html, c#, mvc, model-view-controller, views

Gente, tengo un inconveniente. Requiero que si el número de sorteo va desde el **1 (uno)** al **9 (nueve)** se añadan dos **00 (ceros)** al principio quedando por resultado:

`009`

Y que si el número de sorteo va desde el **10 (diez)** al **99 (noventa y nueve)** se añada un **0 (cero)** quedando por resultado:

`099`

**Clase:**

```
public Nullable<double> Sorteo { get; set; }
public string unCero = "0";
public string dosCeros = "00";
```

Intento añadirlo a la vista, pero el problema es que al hacer esto:

```
if(item.Sorteo>=1 || item.Sorteo<=9)
{
  <p class="nSorteo">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dosCeros)@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sorteo)</p>
}
else if(item.Sorteo>=10 || item.Sorteo<=99)
{
  <p class="nSorteo">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.unCero)@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sorteo)</p>
}
else
{
  <p class="nSorteo">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sorteo)</p>
}
```

En la vista siempre se ve:

```
009//se añaden dos ceros cuando es una sola cifra, esto si está bien
0050//se añaden dos ceros cuando son dos cifras, esto está mal porque tiene que quedar 050
```

Es decir, siempre se añaden los dos ceros, ¿Hay algo mal en la condición? ¿Cómo puedo conseguir que se vea como quiero?

Comment: Y un `String.format`?

Comment: ¿Funciona con tipo `double?`? @PauloUrbanoRivera

Comment: Sin ningún problema! Aunque si es de _0 a N_ es `Int` no? De todas formas funcionara tambien

Comment: Pues lo solucioné añadiendo en la clase dos variables de tipo string y luego mmostrándolas en la vista, pero el problema es que siempre me muestra los dos 00 así que modificaré la pregunta @PauloUrbanoRivera

Comment: La condicion esta mal.. deberia ser `&&`

Comment: Tienes razón, era eso. Gracias, ¿podrías ponerlo como respuesta para poder dar por terminada la pregunta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basado en la forma en que lo estás trabajando, la condición debería ser un `AND` no un `OR`.

```
if(item.Sorteo>=1 && item.Sorteo<=9)
{
  <p class="nSorteo">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dosCeros)@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sorteo)</p>
}
```

y listo! :)

Answer (score 1):

Puede funcionar esto para ti?

```
public class Model
{
    public Nullable<double> Sorteo { get; set; }
    public string PrintSorteo
    {
        get { return Sorteo.HasValue ? Sorteo.Value < 10 ? $"00{Sorteo.Value}" : $"0{Sorteo.Value}" : string.Empty; }
    }
}
```

Para mantener la lógica en el lado del servidor y solo mostrar los resultados en el lado del cliente:

```
<p class="nSorteo">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PrintSorteo)</p>
```